# WireMock To Use As Proxy For SOAP Service

Tags: integration-testing, http-proxy, wiremock

Here is the scenario I'm trying to work on:

I'm writing Contract Driven Tests using Spring Cloud Contract. The tests for inter-communication between the microservices works fine.

Some microservices are calling SOAP-based services. As part of integration tests, I'm trying to use
WireMock as a proxy for the SOAP-based services. Basically, the WireMock should intercept the call, then call the target live environment with the same request, return the same response to the test as a stub.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples how to proceed with that. These services use the HTTP protocol. Any examples of how or any pointers to achieve this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide details of the SOAP client you're using and how it's set up? Which library are you using and how are you integrating it into your app?

Also, are you able to change the base URL or hostname/port of the SOAP endpoint it calls?

Comment: Hi @Tom - SOAP client is implemented using cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws, cxf-rt-transports-http. It is implemented in a separate doa library which is added as a dependency to main application. Yes, I can update the base URL in the test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to point your SOAP client to the WireMock base URL, so e.g. if you're using a Spring properties file you might have something like this:

```
soap.api.host=wiremock-host.internal
soap.api.port=8888
```

Then you need to configure the WireMock server with a low-priority, broad matching proxy stub. Here's an example of how that would look in JSON form:

```
{
  "priority": 8,
  "response": {
    "proxyBaseUrl" : "http://target.soap.endpoint"
  }
}
```

Then finally, you would create additional stubs (at the default priority) for each request you want to intercept e.g.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/v1/some/thing",
    "headers": {
      "SOAPAction": {
        "contains": "MyAction"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "<soap:Envelope ..."
  }
}
```